# .NetWebApi refresh token expires after 20 minutes

Tags: .net, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, token

Net WebApi application hosted on a server.
I wanted to implemented the token based approach in order to authorize.
Therefore I wrote a TokenProvider and a RefreshTokenProvider.
I set the access token to expire after 10 minutes and the refresh token to expire after 1 day.
But somehow the refresh token expires after 20 minutes. I already researched the problem. Due to the problem I manually set the machine key in the webconfig, so the token will still be available after the application pool was recycled, which did not solve the problem.

I currently store the refresh token in a concurrentdictionary. Is it bad? Should I store it in the database?

AuthorizationServerProvider (Refresh token parts):

```
public override async Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
  foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
  {
    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
  }
}

public override async Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
{
  var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Identity);
  newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("newClaim", "refreshToken"));

  var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newIdentity, context.Ticket.Properties);
  context.Validated(newTicket);
}
```

SimpleRefreshTokenProvider:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket> refreshTokens =
  new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket>();
protected readonly log4net.ILog log;

public SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
{
  this.log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
}

public void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
{
  var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  var refreshTokenDaysLifeTime = 1;
  AuthenticationProperties refreshTokenProperties = new AuthenticationProperties(context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary);
  refreshTokenProperties.IssuedUtc = context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc;
  refreshTokenProperties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(refreshTokenDaysLifeTime*(60*24)));

  context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = refreshTokenProperties.IssuedUtc;
  context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = refreshTokenProperties.ExpiresUtc;
  AuthenticationTicket refreshTokenTicket =
    new AuthenticationTicket(context.Ticket.Identity, refreshTokenProperties);

  refreshTokens.TryAdd(guid, refreshTokenTicket);
  this.log.Info($"Added refresh token: {guid}. Should expire on {refreshTokenTicket.Properties.ExpiresUtc}");

  context.SetToken(guid);
}

public void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
{
  AuthenticationTicket ticket;
  if (refreshTokens.TryRemove(context.Token, out ticket))
  {
    this.log.Info($"Used refresh token to receive access token: {context.Token}");
    context.SetTicket(ticket);
  }
}
```

I am grateful for every hint thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution was quite stupid.

I actually wanted to prevent the pool to recycle a dictionary I was keeping the refresh tokens in. Since it is hosted with a provider I could not adjust the recycle time, so every time the pool was refreshed, I lost all refresh tokens.
In the end I simply stored my refresh tokens in a database.